# In Lightroom, how do I search for photos which match only a certain keyword?

Tags: software, lightroom, keywords, search

How do I get Lightroom to return photos that contain a *single* word I search for?

Example:

I have pictures that I have keyworded with two names, Max and Maddie.  I have pictures of Max on his own (keyword Max) pictures of Maddie on her own (keyword Maddie) pictures af them both together (keywords Max, Maddie).  If I search in the keyword text for Max, I am getting the pictures of him on his own (which is what I want) but also the ones of both of them together.  So, how do I get just Max on his own to return?

Answer (score 2):

It actually works the way you would expect, it's just not documented (at least as far as I know...I had to experiment to figure this out). In library module, grid mode, enable **Text** search. Choose **Keywords -> Contain**, and type in "Max !Maddie". You should get a list of results that contain the keyword Max exclusive of the keyword Maddie.

Now, that is not the same as a purely exclusive keyword search that will only find things with just the one keyword "Max". That is different than a "keyword exclusive of" search where you explicitly exclude one or more keywords in favor of one or more keywords. If you truly want to search for just a single keyword and nothing else at all, I am not really sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is:

- Find the `Max` keyword in the Library's Keyword List panel
- Hover over it, then click the right arrow next to it to show photos with that keyword
- In the Library Filter bar's Text section, select "Keywords" → "Don't contain" → `Maddie`"

You can build on this, such as by multi-selecting keywords in the metadata filter in the normal way.

If you need something more powerful than this, you can step up to [Any Filter](http://www.johnrellis.com/lightroom/anyfilter.htm). It isn't real-time like the LR built in filters, but it can do more. For example, if you have a `Max > cousins > family` keyword hierarchy and search for `cousins` with the built-in filtering, you will also get photos with the `Max` keyword. That is often what you want, but maybe you're trying to show photos generically tagged `cousins`. That is, those without any person name keywords. In this case, you can use Any Filter to collect those photos with the exact keyword `cousins`.

Comment: Thanks for both the answers, I'm sure both solutions will work for me.